# Question about memory when loading many unique sprites in Unity game using addressables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

In our Unity game, we are creating a 2D first person game (Myst-style), so we naturally have many many Texture2Ds. We didn't think much of it until we starting experiencing crashes on older iOS devices due to memory issues. So I need to change the loading of Texture2Ds from all at once in the scene to instead be loaded on the fly at runtime using addressables.

I watched the 2018 lecture on addressables, but he didn't seem to answer my main question, which is: If I were to have all my textures in one group (which from what I understand is equivalent to an asset bundle), if I load just one texture, will it load the entire group, and thereby put all of the group into memory?

I need to know whether it is okay to have them in the same group (or whether grouping makes a difference in memory) or whether I would need to make the groups much smaller for memory efficiency. If the latter would be the case, would it just be better time-wise to use Resources.LoadAsync()?

Answer (score 0):

I received a good answer to the question here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/addressable-group-memory-question.701669/

Recap: Loading an individual addressable asset is on-demand and doesn't require unloading the entire group. Groups are more for organization and logic.